# How can I print 413284921265094656?

Tags: javascript, string, int

```
alert(413284921265094656 + "");
```

but it prints `413284921265094660`, even if I "convert" it in string.

Comment: maybe `alert("413284921265094656");` is it you want?

Comment: @CesarMiguel: yes, but I got 413284921265094656 from a json, so I need to "convert" in string before.

Comment: @dvnrrs solv your problem?

Comment: No, that's just seems to be the only solution, use a library :(

Comment: Can be only solution. From what i read, your json result is to longer. Good luck using library ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand the question, but...

```
alert("413284921265094656")
```

The interpreter is trying to store 413284921265094656 as a double-precision floating point number, but the number exceeds the precision limit, so the least significant bits are being lost. You can't store a number with that much precision (roughly speaking, that many digits or "significant figures") in JavaScript without use of a [big-int library](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js).